# Testrpc not showing output?

Tags: solidity

When I use Javascript VM in Remix I'm able to run functions and return outputs, but when I switch over to testrpc, the code runs properly but there's no decoded output.

I only ever run into this problem when I need to return a  `bool` or the `now` variable. Is there any way explanation as to why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

So as you know Remix runs Ethereum-vm underneath so sometimes it's a bit different from testRPC. Try testing with https://ethfiddle.com as well to double check output.

Anyways, back to your question. Did you add `constant` to the function declaration? Otherwise you'll just get a txHash unless you've implemented events.

```
  contract SimpleReturn {
    bool value = false;

    function get() public constant returns (bool) {
      return value;
    }
  }
```

^ the above function returns a bool perfectly fine.

see it running: https://ethfiddle.com/wzk5p9qLdw

Comment: So I actually just tested the returning `now` with and without `constant` and having `constant` returns output. However, for another function I'm trying to return I have `payable` and I don't think I'm allowed to have both `payable` and `constant` right?

Comment: thats correct, if you declare the function as payable, it will return a txhash and also cost gas. link: https://ethfiddle.com/0pxC4R-F_1

Comment: What if I want a payable function to also return a true?

Comment: you need to use events: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events